# Is $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}x\cdot f(\sin x)dx=\pi \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\sin x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

How can I prove that for all continuous $f$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}x\cdot f(\sin x)dx$$
$$=\pi  \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin x)dx$$

Comment: Try the change of variable $u=\pi-x$.